# Lazy loaded EF6 entity stops working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a web api running in azure. The api uses a sql database, also running in azure.

The api uses code first approach and lets entity framework 6.1.3 construct the database. Everything is lazy loaded and no explicit eager loading has been used on any of the entities.

This has been working very well, but we have recently encountered a strange issue which we have yet to find the reason for. After deploying the api it will after some time, it could be minutes, hours or days not load the related entities when they are accessed. Instead all the related entities will be *null*. To be noted is that this system is still only in development so the traffic is fairly limited.

We notice this usually with the user entity, which is used to perform login, althought we have seein it in other parts of the system as well. The entity will all of a sudden, for no clear reason, start having null in all its related entity tables.

I've tried debugging the azure api when the problem occurs and indeed, the user object retrieved from the database has only its own data set, an all related tables are null. Once the problem occurs the only solution is to redeploy the api whereupon everything starts working again and the retrieved user entity and its related entities will again all have the expected data.

The database is still the same when and after the problem occurs.

This is my User BusinessEntity:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

To include one of the related entities, this is the Person businessentity:

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public string PersonNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping the User entity like this:

```
public class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        //Key
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        //table specific field settings
        Property(u => u.Username).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();

        //table name
        ToTable(nameof(User));

        //relationship
        HasOptional(u => u.Person)
            .WithRequired(p =>p.User);            
    }
}
```

This is where I get a user entity from the database using a username and password:

```
    User GetUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = _context.User
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(userName) && x.Password.Equals(password));
        return user;
    }
```

And finally my returned user entity is used to set an identity using the loaded user with its related enties (person etc.). I wont get any firstname, lastname etc. becuse of the strange issue I'm facing.

```
    internal static void SetThreadIdentity(User user)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name == string.Empty)
        {
            var identity = new BasicAuthenticationIdentity(
                username: user.Username,
                password: user.Password,
                firstName: user.Person?.FirstName,
                lastName: user.Person?.LastName,
                personNumber: user.Person?.PersonNumber,
                userId: user.Id);

            var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

A work around is to add a bunch of .Include() calls to eager load the related enties in my GetUser method. And while this fixes the problem it does not explain why the lazy load stops working after some time.

Comment: When this occurs, can you check the values of _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled and _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled?

Comment: Are that dozen of fields essential for your question? Consider providing minimal code sample.

Comment: Right you are stop-cran my bad, i cleaned up some code from my example.

Comment: I have tried to manually add _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false when I've been fiddling around with the settings. Aside from that I havn't changed these settings so they should be the default true. I will check when the error occurs though. Good call

Comment: Does this all happen in one request?

Comment: Could `_context` be getting disposed before `SetThreadIdentity` is called?  Or could it be garbage collected, which might explain the random occurrence.

Comment: Yes it happens in any one request.
A simplified example flow could be (to relate to supplied code):
Request come in -> Via AuthorizeAttribute override basicauth is extracted from header -> username/password are used to get the user.

I dont think the GC is the issue as the db is still accessable via _context (both read and write) only the related entities won't load for any requested entity, though the main entity is loaded. The problem randomly starts, but then it persists until i redeploy the API. I'm not sure if its fixed by a restart, I will try that next.

Comment: LazyLoadingEnabled = false when the error occurs! That is so werid. I never touch this setting. But I found the reason for issue, thank you @PMV

Comment: What's the life cycle of `_context`? When is it initialized and disposed?